# Spring HATEOAS with OpenAPI Generator

Tags: spring-hateoas, openapi-generator

I have an OpenAPI specification and generating code for my spring boot application. The RequestMapping contains a variable with a default value after generating the code.

```
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2022-05-12T12:55:38.660504+02:00[Europe/Berlin]")
@Controller
@RequestMapping("${openapi.tenantapp.base-path:/api/v1}")
public class TenantsApiController implements TenantsApi {
...
}
```

But when creating HATEOAS links the variable is not resolved and used as-is instead:

```
        tenantDTO.ifPresent(dto -> dto.add(linkTo(methodOn(TenantsApiController.class)
            .getTenantByTenantKey(tenantKey)).withSelfRel()));
```

Result:

```
    {
        "links": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/${openapi.tenantapp.base-path/api/v1}/tenants/c9b7122c-abf8-4c56-8fbd-740b27183d4d",
                "rel": "self"
            }
        ],
        "tenantKey": "c9b7122c-abf8-4c56-8fbd-740b27183d4d"
    }
```

Seems that Spring HATEOAS does not recognize the String as a variable. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem. If you use the openapi-generator < 6.1 (6.0.1 worked for us), the @RequestMapping annotation will not be generated, thus the links are correct.

Reported this to the generator as well:
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/13552

Comment: It's not an error with the generator. Using an embdded value or even Spring EL in your request mapping is completely valid. It's a bug in Spring HATEOAS. I created this bug https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/1855 back in September. There are also 26 outstanding PR's some of which are more than a year old.

We ended up writting our own, that uses OpenAPI annotations instead.